How can I use active learning and combine 2 weighted approaches to find the ideal probability of picking similar 2 objects to compare?
The ultimate  goal is to provide to the user pairs of objects, let's say tables, that the users must vote between them based on aesthetic appearance. Each session there 30 comparisons, so 30 pairs of tables to compare to. I ultimately want to form pairs of tables which are close in terms of aesthetic quality and hence more difficult comparisons, because if a table is significantly better than the other, then this comparison should be displayed less often (but still retain some small probability ), after figuring out which is better after all.
I want to combine 2 approaches. First off, Each table has a aesthetic rating in a 1-10 scale. So, The first of the 2 approaches is to take into account the these ratings, so as tables with close ratings to one another should be matched to make a pair more often than not. As the ratings differ, the probability should be slimmer. I attempt of tackling that with a Gaussian distribution, as provided in the code below.
The second part is the comparisons that we collect from the users along the way. So, if a certain comparison with 2 tables (ids) has been registered 100 times and and 90 times the first table was chosen over the other, then the probability of this specific comparison to be repeated should be slimmer, than another pair where the choices were 50-50 and thus unsettled. There is a way, Bradley-Terry model, which can transform these comparisons into numbers, as shown below
So, I want to combine these methods , giving them a weight (0.5 each I guess) but I am not sure how can I do that. As of now, this is the code:
    
 // Assuming `images` is a rating sorted array of images
function pickImages(images, numPairs) {
  let pairs = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
    // Pick a random index for the first image
    let index1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

    // Pick a second index near the first one with weighted probability
    let index2 = pickIndexNear(index1, images.length);

    pairs.push([images[index1], images[index2]]);


  return pairs;
}


// Function to pick an index near the specified index with weighted probability
function pickIndexNear(index, arrayLength) {
  // Define the standard deviation of the Gaussian distribution
  let stdDev = 40;

  // Generate a random number from a Gaussian distribution centered at the specified index
  let randomOffset = Math.round(randn_bm() * stdDev);

  // Ensure the second index is within the array bounds
  let index2 = Math.max(0, Math.min(arrayLength - 1, index + randomOffset));

  return index2;
}

// Standard Normal variate using Box-Muller transform.
function randn_bm() {
  var u = 0, v = 0;
  while(u === 0) u = Math.random(); //Converting [0,1) to (0,1)
  while(v === 0) v = Math.random();
  return Math.sqrt( -2.0 * Math.log( u ) ) * Math.cos( 2.0 * Math.PI * v );
} 

// generate a random integer number between [low, high)
function randomInteger(low, high) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low)
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }

  return array;
}


function BradleyTerryScores(comparisons) {
  const epsilon = 0.0001; // convergence threshold
  let scores = {}; // initialize scores

  // Initialize scores to 1
  for (let comparison of comparisons) {
    scores[comparison.im1] = 1;
    scores[comparison.im2] = 1;
  }

  let maxDiff;

  do {
    let newScores = {};
    let totalScore = 0;

    // Calculate new scores
    for (let comparison of comparisons) {
      let winScore = comparison.w1;
      let loseScore = comparison.w2;
      newScores[comparison.im1] = winScore / (winScore + loseScore);
      newScores[comparison.im2] = loseScore / (winScore + loseScore);
      totalScore += newScores[comparison.im1] + newScores[comparison.im2];
    }

    maxDiff = 0;

    // Normalize scores and check for convergence
    for (let imageId in scores) {
      newScores[imageId] /= totalScore;
      let diff = Math.abs(newScores[imageId] - scores[imageId]);
      if (diff > maxDiff) {
        maxDiff = diff;
      }
    }

    scores = newScores;
  } while (maxDiff > epsilon);

  return scores;
}

Also, here are the objects images and comparisons that I have in my database. (I am open to add attributes)
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')

/*
  Schema description:
    - im1 : first image id
    - im2 : second image id
    - w1 : number of times the first image won
    - w2 : number of times the second image won
    - t : number of times the comparison was displayed (w1 + w2)
    - u : is true if the comparison is displayed in a vote
      session at the moment
*/
const ComparisonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Number,
  im1: Number,
  im2: Number,
  w1: Number,
  w2: Number,
  t: Number,
  u: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}, { collection: 'comparisons' })


module.exports = mongoose.model('Comparison', ComparisonSchema)


    
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

/*
  Schema description:
    - imageID :  image id
    - website : the website name 
    - averageRating : the mean rating that was collected during the rating process only by users
*/
const ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    imageID: Number,
    website: String,
    averageRating: Number,
//   u: {
//     type: Boolean,
//     default: false
//   }
}, { collection: 'images' })


module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema)

